# Wordpress CPT Archive Pagination - Displays too many pages

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type

I've been trying to figure out why my custom post type archive is displaying too many pages in the pagination.

My pagination is being displayed by FacetWP using the following code:

```
<?php echo facetwp_display('pager'); ?>
```

I've tried customizing how it displays, but each time it still continues to show too many pages. However, when I select a filter, then the pages will be correct.

Is there a way to make it so that it will automatically display the number of pages for each custom post type archive?

EDIT: Since I’m not an advanced php user myself, I've only tried the customization code provided by FacetWP's documentation.

```
$params = array(
'page' => 1,
'per_page' => 10,
'total_rows' => 205,
'total_pages' => 21 );
```

And

```
add_filter( 'facetwp_pager_html', function( $output, $params ) {
$output = '';

if ( 1 < $params['total_pages'] ) {
    for ( $i = 1; $i <= $params['total_pages']; $i++ ) {
        $is_curr = ( $i === $params['page'] ) ? ' active' : '';
        $output .= '<a class="facetwp-page' . $is_curr . '" data-page="' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a>';
    }
}

return $output; }, 10, 2 );
```

And

```
function my_facetwp_pager_html( $output, $params ) {
$output = '';
$page = $params['page'];
$total_pages = $params['total_pages'];
if ( $page > 1 ) {
    $output .= '<a class="facetwp-page" data-page="' . ($page - 1) . '">Previous</a>';
}
if ( $page < $total_pages && $total_pages > 1 ) {
    $output .= '<a class="facetwp-page" data-page="' . ($page + 1) . '">Next</a>';
}
return $output; } add_filter( 'facetwp_pager_html', 'my_facetwp_pager_html', 10, 2 );
```

Sorry if any of that code is messy, let me know if I need to repost for clarification. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Hi, welcome on SO. What did you already tried ?

Comment: Hi @AndréDS, thanks for the reply! I've edited my post to answer your question.